# What is the optimal way to average noisy votes given we know the MSE of each voter?

Tags: statistics, regression, estimation

Let's say we want to know the value of some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and we have $n$ "noisy votes (estimates)" $v_1, v_2, ... v_n$ drawn from $V_1, V_2,..V_n$. For each of these votes, we also have an approximate mean squared error of the voter $E[(V_i - x)^2]$ and all pairwise covariances $Cov(V_i, V_j)$, with $ i, j \in [1...n].$ What is the best way to ensemble the votes to predict $x$?

My thoughts:
Intuitively I feel like if any voters have an MSE of 0, their votes should be averaged and all others neglected. Generalizing, it seems that the weight assigned to each vote should be inversely related to the error. I am not sure how to prove the optimal weighting. Also, is a weighted combination of votes the best we can do, or could a more complex scheme achieve lower error?

Comment: Are you saying that there are votes $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n$ as observations of $V_1,V_2,\ldots, V_n$ and we know the expected mean square errors $m_i=\mathbb E[(V_i-x)^2]$ for each $i$?  Are the votes independent?  Are they centred on $x$ as in $\mathbb E[V_i]  =x$?

Comment: Yes, your first statement is correct. The votes are not independent, but we do know their covariances. And yes, they are centered on X. I'll update the problem description.